# Django 1.7 sending password reset link to user with a html template

Tags: django

Hi i am using Django's built in reset password functionality. But the email sent to user shows only plain text. Is there a way to use html email easily in django 1.7?

Answer (score 0):

In Django 1.7 they added the html_message attribute to the [send_mail()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/email/#send-mail) function. Before 1.7 you had to do a little bit more work and override the [EmailMessage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/email/#the-emailmessage-class) class.

I haven't used the built-in Django authentication stuff for a while (exclusively use django-allauth), but according to the [auth docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/) overriding the email template seems to be built-in:

> email_template_name: The full name of a template to use for generating
>   the email with the reset password link. Defaults to
>   registration/password_reset_email.html if not supplied.

EDIT:
If that doesn't work, try adding the `html_email_template_name` argument to the [password_reset view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset)

Comment: I am overriding it but it still can not send html email. I am getting html as text...

Comment: Looks like you need to set the html email template name in the password_reset view, I edited and linked to the section. Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes i have read that part but  i am using  url(r'^account/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),  in the urls.py so how can i pass ->  html_email_template_name  ... I

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset) could definitely be improved on this section. Here's how to set it up:

```
password_reset(
  email_template_name='your txt template goes here'
  html_email_template_name='your html template goes here'
)
```

This will result in the user getting an HTML email with a txt alternate